# How to set photo in ImageView after taking it? Android Studio

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I am developing an app that requests to take a photo. When the photo is taken a file is created and the file path is used to place the photo in an `ImageView`.

Everything seems to be fine, the camera activity starts and I can take a photo, but when we return back to the calling activity, the `ImageView` keeps coming up as a blank. 
Any suggestions?

Please see my code below

```
 public void takePhotoButtonOnClick(View view) {
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();
    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    photoImage.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

}


static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "hwardak.employeecenter.FileProvider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}


String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = editText_id.getText().toString().trim() + "_photo_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;
}
```

XML

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/photoImage"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:src="@mipmap/empty_profile"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement method `onActivityResult` and then update the `ImageView` there.

also see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result ...eg:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

maybe next time read the whole page, not only the half ...
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: Thanks. I originally tried to use that method but I was given an error on line         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference. "

Also, I'd like to save the absolute path to use later on, so I'm confused as to why I can't display the photo in the ImageView given the absolute path of image file.

Comment: there is no absolute path, unless you save the image ...and the &quot;data&quot; should nevertheless be bundled extras of the returned intent. just set a breakpoint there, learn to debug ...in every case, you have to save it `onActivityResult` and not elsewhere.